# Flex External Configuration File

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, configuration-files

My problem: I have a program in Flex3 that accesses a server. The program itself is on a server and accessed through a web browser. The point is that I don't want to hardcode in the swf file the IP of the server to access, since it changes and for various other reasons...

How can I do that? Can I put a file in the same directory and what then?

Comment: Is the SWF on a different server that the server he acced ?

Comment: since it's same server. localhost should do the trick, no ?

Comment: no, localhost would refer to the server it's currently running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a config file on the same server as the SWF, you should be able to use an `HTTPService` or `URLLoader` with a relative URL rather than absolute.  You can get fancier (changing ports) by accessing the `url` field of your base Application and creating a new absolute URL from that.

If the SWF is hosted separately from the HTML, you can use `BrowserManager` url to build your config url instead.